# WSO2IS-5.3.0 Pb with password management

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I'm migrating my app from wso2is-5.2.0 to wso2is-5.3.0.
In user-mngt.xml I have from 5.2.0

```
<Property name="PasswordJavaRegEx">^[\S]{1,30}$</Property>
<Property name="PasswordJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{1,30}$</Property>
<Property name="PasswordJavaRegExViolationErrorMsg">Password length should be within 1 to 30 characters</Property>
```

In the wso2is-5.3.0 carbon console, I put the same values from Identity Providers > Resident > Password Policies > Password Pattern
and restart wso2is, but I still cannot create a user from webservice, getting the following error :

> Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Password at
>   least should have 6 characters
>           at org.wso2.carbon.identity.governance.listener.IdentityMgtEventListener.handleEvent(IdentityMgtEventListener.java:626)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.identity.governance.listener.IdentityMgtEventListener.handleEvent(IdentityMgtEventListener.java:585)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.identity.governance.listener.IdentityMgtEventListener.doPreAddUser(IdentityMgtEventListener.java:194)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.addUser(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:1514)

whether I check "Enable Password Policy Feature" or not in the carbon console, my values are not taken into account...
Is there a third way (registry ?) to change password policy ?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the matching values for `Password Policy Min Length` (to 1 in your case) and `Password Policy Max Length` (to 30 in your case) at Resident IdP -> Password Policies -> Password Patterns.

All of the min length, max lengths, and pattern should be matched by the given password to become a valid one.

Comment: I did that is not working.
Resident IdP -> Password Policies is the same as Identity Providers > Resident > Password Policies right ? Or there is another link ?
Does it has to be per tenant many ?

Comment: yes, it's the same location. The config there is applied tenant-wise. Are you trying with different tenants?

Comment: Yes OK I was missing the tenant-wise but the migration script is buggy my existing tenant does not have password policies, NPE in the log, it's ok for the new tenant althought. Thanks

Comment: Great! please do raise a JIRA ticket at https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY with the steps you tried and the error you got?