# WSO2IS-5.3.0 Questions about migration script

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I followed the migration guide from wso2is-5.2.0 to wso2is-5.3.0, and I have a lot of question about it, not sure it is the right way but I ask.

> It said : "6. Replace the /repository/components/dropins
>   folder with a copy of the /repository/components/dropins
>   folder. "

That's weird, I have old version of dropins from 5.2.0 like `org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authenticator.facebook-5.1.2.jar` to put 
to the new release where there is already a newer version like  `org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authenticator.facebook-5.1.3.jar` ?
And it is not said about copying `IS5.3.0_MIGRATION_TOOL_HOME/dropins` to `<NEW_IS_HOME>/repository/components/dropins`, I think it is a oversight ?

I put IS5.3.0_MIGRATION_TOOL_HOME/dropins/org.wso2.carbon.is.migrate.client-5.3.0.jar in /repository/components/dropins anyway

> It said : "9. If you have created tenants in the previous WSO2
>   Identity Server version, copy the content in the
>   /repository/tenants directory to the
>   /repository/tenants/ directory."

OK, I have multiple tenants but the tenant directory contains only empty folder, is it normal ?

**Claim config**

Nothing is saying about having created new claim in claim-config.xml
I added some like in wso2is-5.2.0

```
<Dialect dialectURI="http://mycompany.com/claims">
            <Claim>
                <ClaimURI>http://mycompany.com/claims/originalSystem</ClaimURI>
                <DisplayName>Original System</DisplayName>
                <AttributeID>originalSystem</AttributeID>
                <SupportedByDefault />        
            </Claim>
        [...]
```

but they were not imported after migration.
I found I had to add http://wso2.org/claims/photourl and now they are migrated but in the console, looking at the claim list I have

```
Claim URI   http://mycompany.com/claims/originalSystem
Mapped Local Claim  http://wso2.org/claims/migration__photourl__862
```

And using the webservice to get the user claim attribute it is not showing up http://mycompany.com/claims/originalSystem

**Password policy migration**
About the policy password, see ([WSO2IS-5.3.0 Pb with password management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41717808/wso2is-5-3-0-pb-with-password-management/41719959)), when I login with the admin of an existing tenant, looking at identity provider resident UI, i have a white page and the following error in the log...

```
Caused by: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /idpmgt/idp-mgt-edit-local.jsp at line 691

688:                     <%
689:                     org.wso2.carbon.identity.governance.stub.bean.Property[] connectorProperties = connectorConfig.getProperties();
690:                         for (int k = 0; k < connectorProperties.length; k++) {
691:                             String value = connectorProperties[k].getValue();%>
692:                         <tr>
693:                             <td style="width: 500px;">
694:                                 <%=Encode.forHtmlContent(connectorProperties[k].getDisplayName())%>

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.jsp.idpmgt.idp_002dmgt_002dedit_002dlocal_jsp._jspService(idp_002dmgt_002dedit_002dlocal_jsp.java:1019)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
TID: [2] [] [2017-01-18 13:50:32,158] admin@wso2.org@mycompany.com [2] [IS]ERROR {org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RenderTagSupport} -  Error during rendering
javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: IO Error executing tag: JSPException while including path '/idpmgt/idp-mgt-edit-local.jsp'. ServletException while including page.
```

I checked the release beta and rc before wso2is-5.3.0 went out, but I would have been happy to test the migration script before it is released... Is it available on github ?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Step 6 : Yes it should only be the custom added jars, not all.

Step 9 : It may not have any resources unless you added things like secondary userstores, workflows etc

Claim Config : In 5.3.0 all the claims external to wso2 dialect are mapped to the relevant claim in wso2 dialect (not to the underlying attribute). If there are no claim in wso2 dialect mapped to that attribute, client will create one and add the mapping. 
You may either update that claim or create a new claim with proper values at wso2 dialect and map your custom claim to the new claim in wso2 dialect.

Th issue with policy migration could possibly be a bug. Better if you can report it at https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY

The source for the migration resources are available at 
https://github.com/wso2/product-is/tree/master/modules/migration/migration-5.2.0_to_5.3.0

Answer (score 0):

You can find the claim migration details from claim-migration.txt file in the home directory. It has the detailed explanation about the newly created claims and why it is created.

Thanks
Isura