# wso2is-5.3.0 How to update Identity claims

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm still trying to migrate my app from [wso2is-5.2.0 to wsois-5.3.0.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41722809/wso2is-5-3-0-questions-about-migration-script)
My app is a rest api to manage users and I call wso2is soap webservices.

In 5.3.0 it seems that I cannot modified identity claims like identity/accountLocked or identity/failedLoginAttempts with the webservice

> TID: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41722809/wso2is-5-3-0-questions-about-migration-script) [2017-01-19 10:42:26,672] admin@wso2.org@mycompany.com [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41722809/wso2is-5-3-0-questions-about-migration-script)
>   [IS]ERROR {org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver} - 
>   InvalidOperation This operation is not supported for Identity claims
>   org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: InvalidOperation This
>   operation is not supported for Identity claims
>           at org.wso2.carbon.identity.governance.listener.IdentityStoreEventListener.doPreSetUserClaimValue(IdentityStoreEventListener.java:202)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.setUserClaimValue(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:1252)

I need to unlock account manually on certains use-case, or reset failedLoginAttempts for integration-test, is there another webservice / solution to achive that ?

Regards,

Comment: What is the service you tried?

Comment: RemoteUserStoreManagerServiceStub.setUserClaimValue()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You have to use RemoteUserStoreManagerServiceStub.setUserClaimValue**s**() method instead of RemoteUserStoreManagerServiceStub.setUserClaimValue() method. In IS 5.3.0 RemoteUserStoreManagerServiceStub.setUserClaimValue() method is blocked for Identity Claims.

Thanks
Isura

Comment: I rather found UserIdentityMgtAdminClient.lockAccount instead but thanks for your answer.
Any idea how to getUserClaimValue() to see is account is lock or not the 
 
RemoteUserStoreManagerServiceStub.setUserClaimValue return null for accountLock instead of true in the database

Comment: You have to use RemoteUserStoreManagerServiceStub.getUserClaimValues() method.